# How to send a message requests.post

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to create a post request to send a message on the site. But for some reason it doesn't work. I am on the right page, but for some reason the message is still not being sent

```
print(f'{login}', lastChat['userSms'])
Jurl = 'https://funpay.com/chat/?node=userId' 
seska = session.get(Jurl )
soup = BeautifulSoup(seska.text, 'lxml')
tag1 = soup.find('div', id='live-counters').get('data-orders')
tag3 = soup.find('div', class_='chat chat-float').get('data-bookmarks-tag')
tag2 = soup.find("div", class_='chat chat-float').get('data-tag')
tag4 = soup.find('div', class_='param-item chat-panel hidden').get('data-tag')
session.get(Jurl)
dataMes = soup.findAll('div', class_='message')
print(dataMes[-1])
objects = '[{"type":"orders_counters","id":"5214431","tag":"' + tag1 + '","data":false},' \
          '{"type":"chat_node","id":"users-5054677-5214431","tag":"' + tag2 + '",' \
          '"data":{"node":"users-5054677-5214431","last_message":' + lastMes + ',"content":"s"}},' \
          '{"type":"chat_bookmarks","id":"5214431","tag":"' + tag3 + '","data":false},' \
          '{"type":"c-p-u","id":"5054677","tag":"' + tag4 + '","data":false}]'
request = '{"action":"chat_message",' \
          '"data":{"node":"users-5054677-5214431",' \
          '"last_message":' + lastMes + ',"content":"s"}}'
datas = {
    "objects": objects,
    "request": request,
    "csrf_token": csrf
}
print(datas)
session.post(Jurl, data=datas)
```

Comment: Do you see any errors? What's the outcome of the post response?

Comment: post answer 200. There may be an error in the datas itself. But I'm pretty sure that everything is right there

Comment: 200 is a status code. You need to get the **response** from `session.post`, assuming the endpoint actually returns a body

Answer (score 1):

Creating the JSON with concatenated strings is error-prone and most likely it is failing because the JSON won't parse.

For example, if variable `lastMes` is a string value then it must be quoted.

```
request = '{"action":"chat_message",' \
          '"data":{"node":"users-5054677-5214431",' \
          '"last_message":"' + lastMes + '","content":"s"}}'
#                         ^               ^
```

Safer to create a dictionary of the values then use `json.dumps()` to convert the objects to correctly formatted JSON.

```python
import json

tag1 = tag2 = tag3 = tag4 = lastMes = "XXX"
csrf = "csrf"

objects = [{"type": "orders_counters", "id": "5214431", "tag": tag1, "data": False},
           {"type": "chat_node", "id": "users-5054677-5214431", "tag": tag2,
            "data": {"node": "users-5054677-5214431", 
                     "last_message": lastMes, "content": "s"}},
           {"type": "chat_bookmarks", "id": "5214431", "tag": tag3, "data": False},
           {"type": "c-p-u", "id": "5054677", "tag": tag4, "data": False}]
request = {"action": "chat_message",
           "data": {"node": "users-5054677-5214431",
                    "last_message": lastMes,
                    "content": "s"}}

datas = {
    "objects": json.dumps(objects),
    "request": json.dumps(request),
    "csrf_token": csrf
}
```

Then make the HTTP POST and check `r.status_code`.

```
r = session.post(Jurl, data=datas)
print(r.status_code)
```

However, if the web service requires a JSON payload (with Content-type header=application/json) not form-encoded data then you need to use the [json= parameter](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

```python
datas = {
    "objects": objects,
    "request": request,
    "csrf_token": csrf
}
r = session.post(Jurl, json=datas)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't send messages. But K.status_code outputs 200. At the same time, I do not deny the fact that I may be substituting something in datas. But still almost sure that the error is not in datas

Comment: @ВладДаниленко check the documenrtation for the API for that website. Does it require form-encoded data or a posted JSON payload? If you call `r = session.post(Jurl, data=datas)` does it also respond with 200 status?

Comment: There is no documentation for this site. When data=datas also outputs 200

Comment: @ВладДаниленко reworked the answer to fix improperly escaped JSON. Even a single typo will cause it to fail.